# GeoScript change layer's projection

Tags: javascript, geoserver, wps

I am using geoscript to reproject a layer in my geoserver.

I can use geoserver/catalog to access a layer's projection with no issue.

However, I can't change it. My code is like this:

```
var catalog = require("geoserver/catalog");
var Process = require("geoscript/process").Process;
var Layer = require("geoscript/layer").Layer;
var Projection = require("geoscript/proj").Projection;

exports.process = new Process({
  inputs: {
    sentence: {
      type: "String"
    }
  },
  outputs: {
    old: {
      type: "String"
    },
    neo: {
      type: "String"
    },
    temp: {
      type: "Boolean"
    }
  },
  run: function() {
    var namespace = catalog.namespaces[0].alias;
    var myPrj = Projection("EPSG:2008");
    var myLayer = catalog.getVectorLayer("test:counties");
    //catalog.getVectorLayer("test:counties").projection = myPrj;
    return {
      old: myLayer.projection,
      neo: myPrj,
      temp: myLayer.temporary
    };
  }
});
```

The code I commented line never works however wps doesn't tell me any error.

Do you know how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.